# Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] External table is not in the expected format., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect

Tags: php, dbf, dsn

I am using odbc_connect() to connect php to .dbf files, i tried adding "Microsoft dBase Drive (*.dbf)" to my System DNS. although the connection was successful from my code I cannot run the odbc_exe() to get the data, it show "External table is not in the expected format"

```
 
   //Storing DSN(Data Source Name created)
  $dsn="myDBFdbDSNConnection";
  $user="";
  $password="";
     
  $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);
  
  if (!$conn)
   {
   echo (die(odbc_error()));
   }
   else
  {
      echo "Connection Successful !";

      $sql="SELECT * FROM table1";
      $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql); 
      
  }
  //Resource releasing
  odbc_close($conn);
```

Comment: Has this table a MEMO field?

Comment: yes its has a memo type field,

Comment: This is possibly the problem... see this thread from 2010: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a989671b-e89e-4136-8ee2-c1dbe8f4d09a/external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-error?forum=winforms

Comment: i tried calling another table without a memo field but i got same result.